# Minimum finger search tree complexity

Tags: time-complexity, balanced-search-trees

Suppose I have an AVL tree with a pointer to the minimal element. I'd like to conduct a search for some key x, which is the $k$-smallest key in the entire tree.
I can do this by "climbing" up the tree's left branch, comparing x with the current key. As long as

> (x > curr.key) && (x > curr.parent.key)

I keep climbing up, but once the second condition is violated, I slide down to the current right-subtree, and from there on it's just a standard BST search.

The claim is that the **worst case** complexity is always $O(\log k)$, for any $k$. But I can't convince myself this is accurate: if x is larger than the tree's root's key (the median, or equivalently $k > {n\over 2}$), that implies I must have traversed the entire left branch, which for a balanced tree is $O(\log n)$ - and only then I can find x in depth of $O(\log k)$.

Am I looking at this the wrong way?

Comment: "The claim is that ...". Can you add a url or reference to the place of that claim?

Comment: It looks like you have understood the whole situation correctly except a minor glitch somewhere.  By the way, if $n\ge k>n/2$, then $O(\log n)$ is $O(\log k)$

Comment: @Apass.Jack The claim was from my class... and no further information on that topic is provided, either. I understand your note, but still - climbing up the tree isn't done in a constant time, the height from the minimum is still $O (\log n)$. The technicality for bigger k's doesn't hold, it seems. So you're saying there's no way to achieve $O(\log n)$ without comparing with the root first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you might be looking it the wrong way.

> If $x$ is larger than the tree's root's key (the median, or equivalently $k>n/2$), that implies I must have traversed the entire left branch, which for a balanced tree is $O(\log n)$ - and only then I can find $x$ in depth of $O(\log k)$.

First, let us be accurate. The root's key may not be the median, although it sits roughly in the middle.

Let $r$ be the root node. Let $n$ be the number of nodes in the whole tree and $n_l$ be the number of nodes in the left subtree of $r$. Let $h_l$ be the height of that subtree and $h$ be the height of the tree, so $h\le h_l+2$ since an AVL tree is height balanced.

Suppose $x$ is larger than the root's key.  That means
$$n_l < k \le n.$$ We also have, according to [the properties of an AVL tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Properties).
$$\log_2 (n+1)\le h \le h_l+2 \le c\log_2(n_l+2)+b +2\lt c\log_2(k+2)+b +2$$ 
where $c\approx 1.44$, $b\approx -0.328$. So, for all $k\ge3$,
$$\log_2(n)\le2\log_2(k)$$

So if you have traversed the entire (height) of the left branch in order find the $k$-th smallest element, you will use $O(\log n) = O(\log k)$ steps.

In fact, if we only look at the subtree whose root is the highest node that we will climb to in search of the $k$-th smallest element, we have just proved that the worst case complexity is always $O(\log k)$